# Command deprecated

Tags: discord, discord.js

So basically I had this blackjack command that worked fine with v12 discord.js but as soon as I updated to discord v13. Bugs starting to appear like:

> node:5932) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead
> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

(Only error showing up)

So I made some research and figured out that what happens to embed, but this command does not content an embed.. I came here to ask help. I would appreciate it :)

**Blackjack.js**

```
const { stripIndents } = require('common-tags');
const { shuffle, verify } = require('../../functions');
const db = require('quick.db');
const suits = ['♣', '♥', '♦', '♠'];
const faces = ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King'];
const hitWords = ['hit', 'hit me'];
const standWords = ['stand'];

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: 'blackjack',
        aliases: ['bj'],
        category: 'games',
        usage: '[deck] <bet>',
        description: 'Play A Game Of Blackjack!',
        accessableby: 'everyone'
    },
    run: async (bot, message, args, ops) => {
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('**Please Enter Your Deck Amount!**')
        let deckCount = parseInt(args[0])
        if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send('**Please Enter A Number!**')
        if (deckCount <= 0 || deckCount >= 9) return message.channel.send("**Please Enter A Number Between 1 - 8!**")

        let user = message.author;
        let bal = db.fetch(`money_${user.id}`)
        if (!bal === null) bal = 0;
        if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send("**Please Enter Your Bet!**")

        let amount = parseInt(args[1])
        if (isNaN(args[1])) return message.channel.send("**Please Enter A Number**")
        if (amount > 10000) return message.channel.send("**Cannot Place Bet More Than \`10000\`**")

        if (bal < amount) return message.channel.send("**You Are Betting More Than You Have!**")
        const current = ops.games.get(message.channel.id);
        if (current) return message.channel.send(`**Please Wait Until The Current Game Of \`${current.name}\` Is Finished!**`);
        try {
            ops.games.set(message.channel.id, { name: 'blackjack', data: generateDeck(deckCount) });
            const dealerHand = [];
            draw(message.channel, dealerHand);
            draw(message.channel, dealerHand);
            const playerHand = [];
            draw(message.channel, playerHand);
            draw(message.channel, playerHand);
            const dealerInitialTotal = calculate(dealerHand);
            const playerInitialTotal = calculate(playerHand);

            if (dealerInitialTotal === 21 && playerInitialTotal === 21) {
                ops.games.delete(message.channel.id);
                return message.channel.send('**Both Of You Just Hit Blackjack!**');
            } else if (dealerInitialTotal === 21) {
                ops.games.delete(message.channel.id);
                db.subtract(`money_${user.id}`, amount);
                return message.channel.send(`**The Dealer Hit Blackjack Right Away!\nNew Balance - **\` ${bal - amount}\``);
            } else if (playerInitialTotal === 21) {
                ops.games.delete(message.channel.id);
                db.add(`money_${user.id}`, amount)
                return message.channel.send(`**You Hit Blackjack Right Away!\nNew Balance -**\`${bal + amount}\``);
            }

            let playerTurn = true;
            let win = false;
            let reason;
            while (!win) {
                if (playerTurn) {
                    await message.channel.send(stripIndents`
                        **First Dealer Card -** ${dealerHand[0].display}
                        **You [${calculate(playerHand)}] -**
                        **${playerHand.map(card => card.display).join('\n')}**
                        \`[Hit / Stand]\`
                    `);
                    const hit = await verify(message.channel, message.author, { extraYes: hitWords, extraNo: standWords });
                    if (hit) {
                        const card = draw(message.channel, playerHand);
                        const total = calculate(playerHand);
                        if (total > 21) {
                            reason = `You Drew ${card.display}, Total Of ${total}! Bust`;
                            break;
                        } else if (total === 21) {
                            reason = `You Drew ${card.display} And Hit 21!`;
                            win = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        const dealerTotal = calculate(dealerHand);
                        await message.channel.send(`**Second Dealer Card Is ${dealerHand[1].display}, Total Of ${dealerTotal}!**`);
                        playerTurn = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    const inital = calculate(dealerHand);
                    let card;
                    if (inital < 17) card = draw(message.channel, dealerHand);
                    const total = calculate(dealerHand);
                    if (total > 21) {
                        reason = `Dealer Drew ${card.display}, Total Of ${total}! Dealer Bust`;
                        win = true;
                    } else if (total >= 17) {
                        const playerTotal = calculate(playerHand);
                        if (total === playerTotal) {
                            reason = `${card ? `Dealer Drew ${card.display}, Making It ` : ''}${playerTotal}-${total}`;
                            break;
                        } else if (total > playerTotal) {
                            reason = `${card ? `Dealer Drew ${card.display}, Making It ` : ''}${playerTotal}-\`${total}\``;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            reason = `${card ? `Dealer Drew ${card.display}, Making It ` : ''}\`${playerTotal}\`-${total}`;
                            win = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        await message.channel.send(`**Dealer Drew ${card.display}, Total Of ${total}!**`);
                    }
                }
            }
            db.add(`games_${user.id}`, 1)
            ops.games.delete(message.channel.id);
            if (win) {
                db.add(`money_${user.id}`, amount);
                return message.channel.send(`**${reason}, You Won ${amount}!**`);
            } else {
                db.subtract(`money_${user.id}`, amount);
                return message.channel.send(`**${reason}, You Lost ${amount}!**`);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            ops.games.delete(message.channel.id);
            throw err;
        }

        function generateDeck(deckCount) {
            const deck = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < deckCount; i++) {
                for (const suit of suits) {
                    deck.push({
                        value: 11,
                        display: `${suit} Ace!`
                    });
                    for (let j = 2; j <= 10; j++) {
                        deck.push({
                            value: j,
                            display: `${suit} ${j}`
                        });
                    }
                    for (const face of faces) {
                        deck.push({
                            value: 10,
                            display: `${suit} ${face}`
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            return shuffle(deck);
        }

        function draw(channel, hand) {
            const deck = ops.games.get(channel.id).data;
            const card = deck[0];
            deck.shift();
            hand.push(card);
            return card;
        }

        function calculate(hand) {
            return hand.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value).reduce((a, b) => {
                let { value } = b;
                if (value === 11 && a + value > 21) value = 1;
                return a + value;
            }, 0);
        }
    }
};
```

**Event Handler**:

```
const { readdirSync } = require("fs")

module.exports = (bot) => {
    const load = dirs => {    
        const events = readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}/`).filter(d => d.endsWith('.js'));
        for (let file of events) {
            const evt = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
            let eName = file.split('.')[0];
            bot.on(eName, evt.bind(null, bot));
          };
        };
        ["client", "guild"].forEach(x => load(x));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

message is an event.  you have an event handler, which fires, when a message event is triggered by a user.  (they send a message).

What this error is saying is that the message event is deprecated.  messageCreate (or messageUpdate) are the new events, and your event handlers need to use that syntax to address the message events (accordingly to creation or update).

Comment: I don't quite understand, english my third language :). But if I give you my event handler could you tell me what changes should be made and give me explaination? (event handler in question)